# Need help to implement PhoneGap/Cordova ContentSync Plugin

Tags: http, xmlhttprequest, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Have a question regarding contentsync phonegap plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/phonegap-plugin-contentsync).
Will be very appreciated if someone could help.
The core of the problem is that my REST server allowing me to download .epub files (witch are same as .zip)  only by sending GET request similar to:

```
https://test-api.books.com/api/getPublishedEpub?session_hash=1235&publication_id=abv1243'
```

Providing this link to the plugin '.sync' call I get a 'Invalid request method' response from the server...
While trying to download ordinary .zip everything works just fine.

```
var pub_id = $scope.currentBook.publication_id, epubUrl = 'https://test-api.books.com/api/getEpub?session_hash='
 + $rootScope.sessionHash+ '&publication_id=' + pub_id;

                        var downloadBtn = document.getElementById("downloadBtn");
                        console.log('Download cliked');
                        var sync = ContentSync.sync({ src: epubUrl, id: 'book'+ pub_id});


                        sync.on('progress', function (data) {
                                downloadBtn.innerHTML = "Downloading: " + data.progress + "%";
                        });

                        sync.on('complete', function (data) {
                                console.log(data.localPath);
                                for (var x = 1; x <= 17; x++) {
                                        var fileUrl = "file://" + data.localPath;
                                        console.log(fileUrl);
                                }

                                downloadBtn.innerHTML = 'Download';
                        });
```